# How to find all combination of distances between last two indexes in tuple list in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop

If I have a list like this:

```
mList = [[[4,3,2], [65,24,34]],\ 
[[424,242,234]],[[42323,2432,234]],\ 
[[24,234,2442],[24,1213,1231]]]
```

where

```
      m1 is sub-list [[4,3,2], [65,24,34]]
          where m1p1=[4,3,2]
                m1p2=[65,24,34]
      m2 is sub-list  [[424,242,234]],[[42323,2432,234]] 
          where m2p1=[424,242,234]
                m2p2=[42323,2432,234]
      m3 is sub-list [[24,234,2442],[24,1213,1231]] 
          where m3p1=[24,234,2442]
                m3p2=[24,1213,1231]
```

the three elements within the lists in `m1`, `m2` and `m3` are [x-coordinate, y coordinate, time], e.g., for m3p1, x coordinate is 24, y coordinate is 234 and time is 2442 but time is irrelevant for my problem.

I need to write a program that takes all x and y coordinates from last two indexes of mList, for now m2 and m3, and create lengths between all these x and y points **to store in a list.**

Therefore, there will be lengths calculated ONLY between x coordinates and y coordinates in different sublists m2 and m3 in combinations of (m2p1 and m3p1), (m2p2 and m3p1), (m2p1 and m3p2), (m2p2 and m3p2) but NOT between p1 and p2 in a certain sublist m2 or m3 so (m2p1 and m2p2), and (m3p1 and m3p2) lengths WILL NOT be calculated.

I can calculate the length using math.hypot() formula but I need a for loop that works even if more items are added to m2 or m3, like m2p3,m3p3, m3p4, or there are more items appended in mList like m4, m5. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any tuples in your question. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think your list is created incorrectly. Could you make sure the brackets are in the right places?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in mList:
    for j in i:
        for k in mList:
           if k != i:
               for l in k:
                   put the code to compare j with l here.
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: That looks very nested. Probably a good idea to refactor your code to make it a little more readable and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
import math

# configurable list
mList = [[[4,3,2], [65,24,34]], \
[[424,242,234],[42323,2432,234]],\
[[24,234,2442],[24,1213,1231]]]

# list to contain the result
distanceList = []

# m1 and m2 the last 2 elements
m1 = mList[-1]
m2 = mList[-2]

for mp1 in m1:
    for mp2 in m2:
        # addend the length between the x and y
        distanceList.append([math.hypot(mp1[0], mp2[0]), math.hypot(mp1[1], mp2[1])])

print distanceList
```